# Python lxml changes tag hierarchy?

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml

I'm having a small issue with lxml. I'm converting an XML doc into an HTML doc.
The original XML looks like this (it looks like HTML, but it's in the XML doc):

```
<p>Localization - Eiffel tower? Paris or Vegas <p>Bayes theorem p(A|B)</p></p>
```

When I do this (item is the string above)

```
lxml.html.tostring(lxml.html.fromstring(item))
```

I get this:

```
<div><p>Localization - Eiffel tower? Paris or Vegas </p><p>Bayes theorem p(A|B)</p></div>
```

I don't have any problem with the <div>s, but the fact that the 'Bayes theorem' paragraph is no longer nested within the outer paragraph is a problem.

Anyone know why lxml is doing this and how to stop it? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

lxml is doing this because it doesn't store invalid HTML, and `<p>` elements [can't be nested](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) in HTML:

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

Comment: Huh. That is something I did not know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're using lxml's HTML parser, not an XML parser.  Try this instead:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> item = '<p>Eiffel tower? Paris or Vegas <p>Bayes theorem p(A|B)</p></p>'
>>> root = etree.fromstring(item)
>>> etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
'<p>Eiffel tower? Paris or Vegas <p>Bayes theorem p(A|B)</p></p>\n'
```