# django weird behavior with safe filter

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

First, look at this code:

```
...
<p class="entry-content">{{ entry.content|safe }}</p>
...
```

The problem is it renders to something like this:

```
...
<p class="entry-content"></p>
{{ entry.content|safe }}
...
```

However, when I use `div` tag instead of `p` everything works alright.

Why does it happen and is there a way to fix it without JavaScript?

EDIT: The problem occurs when `{{ entry.content }}` has block tags like `div`.
EDIT2: in console everything works fine. The problem occurs in browser only.

Comment: I reckon this is an html issue (mismatching open/closing tags), not so much a django thing, please add your entry.content to the post

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide Without safe filter it displays fine. I was fixing it with JavaScript before.

Comment: So please add the incorrect html snippet directly from the page's source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.
It turns out that `p` tag cannot contain block elements.
I found it here: [Python lxml changes tag hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180919/python-lxml-changes-tag-hierarchy#answer-7180990)

The solution is to use `div` instead of `p` and everything will be fine.